# bios version/date and windows installation date

Tags: windows, laptop, bios, date, version

i bought a laptop in july 2020 and the manufacture date that it has is march 2020. which i was happy about ,but the bios version date shows date of 2019 and someone told me that the windows installation date that should show in the computer should be the date of manufacture and not the date of buying it . so my doubt is that:-

1. what should the windows installation date be (the date of manufacture i.e march 2020 or date of purchase i.e july 2020) mine shows the date of purchase
2. what is with the bios version date as it shows a date of 2019 instead of 2020

please someone clarify these things to me as i am getting very restless to know about it .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> what should the windows installation date be

It's 100% irrelevant. Windows installation date doesn't affect anything.

> what is with the bios version date as it shows a date of 2019 instead of 2020

BIOS is developed before the device hits the market, so its initial date is always before model's release date. Newer BIOS versions are going to be released later on.